# Присвоить значения членам класса в стиле C#

Tags: php, c#, ооп

Есть простой класс с переменными

```
class TestClass {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    public function __construct() {

    }
}
```

Возможно ли сразу задать значения переменным $foo и $bar при создании объекта этого класса, как в C#?

```
$obj = new TestClass() {
    $foo = 1;
    $bar = 2;
};

echo $obj->foo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, PHP не поддерживает инициализаторы объектов. Но как и в любом скриптовом языке, легко добавить подобную функциональность костыльно-ориентированным способом:

```
class TestClass
{
    public $foo = 0;
    public $bar = 0;

    public function __construct ($init = null)
    {
        if (is_array($init)) {
            foreach ($init as $name => $value)
                $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }

    function __toString ()
    {
        return "foo: {$this->foo}, bar: {$this->bar}";
    }
}

$obj = new TestClass();
echo "$obj\n";
$obj = new TestClass(['bar' => 2]);
echo "$obj\n";
$obj = new TestClass(['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2]);
echo "$obj\n";
```

Вывод:

```
foo: 0, bar: 0
foo: 0, bar: 2
foo: 1, bar: 2
```

Подобную функциональность обычно выносят в какой-нибудь базовый класс типа "Component". Если нет возможности менять базовый класс, то можно добавить глобальную функцию и писать инициализацию отдельной сторокой.